# How to find and replace 2 integers in a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like: "Total time: 3 hours and 15 minutes", the text could be different, but it always has 2 integers and always in the order hours and then minutes.

I then calculate new hours / minutes based on fields and other values, and thus I have to update the old string. What's the best way in javascript to match the first and second integer in that string and replace them with the new values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This methods will **preserve the original string**, allowing edits to the numbers.

http://jsfiddle.net/cgVgq/

```
str = "Total time: 3 hours and 15 minutes";

//get all groups of numbers and non-numbers
var matches = str.match(/([\d]+|[^\d]+)/g);

//assumes there will be exactly two distinct numbers
matches[1] = parseFloat(matches[1]) + 42;
matches[3] = parseFloat(matches[3]) + 42;

//replace the string
str = matches.join("") //"Total time: 45 hours and 57 minutes"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = 'Total time: 3 hours and 15 minutes';
var matches = str.match(/\d+/g);
var number1 = Number(matches[0]);
var number2 = Number(matches[1]);
str = str.replace(number1, '11').replace(number2, '22');
alert(str);
```

Comment: what about the case where both numbers are the same?

Comment: [Replace](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) only replaces the first instance (unless a regular expression with the *g* flag is used). So as long as they are replaced in the correct order (and they are) there is no issue.

Comment: @jozxyqk : I tested as mentioned by 'RobG' and it works fine. :) thanks RobG

Comment: there is a problem when the 1st number to replace is equal to the 2nd original number. eg: str = str.replace(number1, '15').replace(number2, '22'); This returns "Total time: 22 hours and 15 minutes", instead of "Total time: 15 hours and 22 minutes"

Comment: @user3349897 : that was my mistake. earlier I put wrong index 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1. can you check my latest updated answer. where I have **matches[0]** and **matches[1]** instead of matches[1] and matches[2]. I am sure that it will solve your problem. Don't forget to mark it as an answer so that it may help other developers.

Answer (score 2):

try this to get hours and minutes

```
var pattern = /\d+/g;
var str = "Total time: 3 hours and 15 minutes";
var matches = str.match(pattern);
var hours = matches[0]; // will be 3
var minutes = matches[1]; // will be 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to update you string as belows:

```
var generateStr = function(hour, minute) {
    return 'Total Time: ' + hour + ' hours and ' + minute + ' minutes'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of regex groups capturing like this:

```
var inputStr = 'Total time: 3 hours and 15 minutes';
var newHours = 4;
var newMinutes = 30;
var outputStr = inputStr.replace(/(^.*?)(\d+)(.*?)(\d+)/,
   '$1' + newHours + '$3' + newMinutes);
```

now `outputStr` is 'Total time: 4 hours and 30 minutes'

**EDIT**

you can also do:

```
var inputStr = 'Total time: 3 hours and 15 minutes';
var outputStr = inputStr.replace(/(^.*?)(\d+)(.*?)(\d+)/,
   function(match, p1, p2, p3, p4){
       p2 = parseInt(p2, 10) + 1;
       p4 = parseInt(p4, 10) + 10;
       return p1 + p2 + p3 + p4;
});
```

Now outputStr will be "Total time: 4 hours and 25 minutes"

Comment: I understood the OP to be that the calculation of new values involved knowing the current values. So they must first be extracted, then replaced.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:--

```
var regex = /\d+/g;
var str = "Total time: 3 hours and 15 minutes";
var numbers = str.match(regex);
var hours = numbers[0]; 
var minutes = numbers[1]; 
alert(hours); 
alert(minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "Total time: 3 hours and 15 minutes";
var r = /(.*?)(\d+)(.*?)(\d+)(.*?)/g;
var m = r.exec(s);
var hh = parseInt(m[2], 10);
var mm = parseInt(m[4], 10);
hh = hh + 1;
mm = mm + 1;
s = s.replace(r, "$1" + hh + "$3" + mm + "$5");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is "best"? Depends on what exactly you are doing and how you define "best", too little information to be able to answer.

There are many ways to achieve this. Don't know what you have tried, or what you have had problems with, you didn't tell us.

But some possibilities.

Javascript

```
var str = 'Total time: 3 hours and 15 minutes',
    arr = str.split(/(\d+)/),
    addHours = 5,
    addMinutes = 30,
    result,
    idx;

arr[1] = +(arr[1]) + addHours;
arr[3] = +(arr[3]) + addMinutes;
result = arr.join('');
console.log(result);

idx = 0;
result = str.replace(/(\d+)/g, function (match, p1, offset, string) {
    idx += 1;
    if (idx === 1) {
        return +(p1) + addHours;
    }

    return +(p1) + addMinutes;
});

console.log(result);

result = str.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)(.*?)(\d+)(.*?)$/).slice(1).reduce(function (acc, cur, index) {
    if (index === 1) {
        acc += +(cur) + addHours;
    } else if (index === 3) {
        acc += +(cur) + addMinutes;
    } else {
        acc += cur;
    }

    return acc;
}, '');

console.log(result);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7dz8L/)

All produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a reusable function based on the original string :

```
<div id="time">Total time: 3 hours and 15 minutes</div>
```

```js
var el = document.getElementById('time');
var refresh = new Function('return [' + (
    el.innerHTML.replace(/'/g, '\\\'').replace(
        /^(\D+)\d+(\D+)\d+(.+)$/, 
        '\'$1\',this[0],\'$2\',this[1],\'$3\''
    )
) + '].join(\'\');');
```

Usage examples :

```
el.innerHTML = refresh.call([1, 2]); // "Total time: 1 hours and 2 minutes"
el.innerHTML = refresh.call([3, 4]); // "Total time: 3 hours and 4 minutes"
```

---

If you don't like arrays :

```
var refresh = new Function('return [' + (
    el.innerHTML.replace(/'/g, '\\\'').replace(
        /^(\D+)\d+(\D+)\d+(.+)$/, 
        '\'$1\',this.hours,\'$2\',this.minutes,\'$3\''
    )
) + '].join(\'\');');
```

Usage examples :

```
el.innerHTML = refresh.call({ hours: 1, minutes: 2 });
el.innerHTML = refresh.call({ hours: 3, minutes: 4 });
```

---

If you don't like `.call()` :

```
var refresh = new Function('time', 'return [' + (
    el.innerHTML.replace(/'/g, '\\\'').replace(
        /^(\D+)\d+(\D+)\d+(.+)$/, 
        '\'$1\',time.hours,\'$2\',time.minutes,\'$3\''
    )
) + '].join(\'\');');
```

Usage examples :

```
el.innerHTML = refresh({ hours: 1, minutes: 2 });
el.innerHTML = refresh({ hours: 3, minutes: 4 });
```

---

### Going further

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/W4Xx8/.

```
<div id="time">Total time: 3 hours and 15 minutes</div>
```

```js
var refreshTime = function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('time');
    var tpl = new Function('return [' + (
        el.innerHTML.replace(/'/g, '\\\'').replace(
            /^(\D+)\d+(\D+)\d+(.+)$/, 
            '\'$1\',this.hours,\'$2\',this.minutes,\'$3\''
        )
    ) + '].join(\'\');');
    return function (data) {
        el.innerHTML = tpl.call(data);
    };
}();
```

```js
refreshTime({ hours: 1, minutes: 2 });
```